# Facebook with older version but i want app invites How?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, ios8

Is it possible to update the Facebook SDK? I am using Version 2.0. The problem is completed the Application.

My application is integrated with Facebook with older version but I want Facebook application share, invites option.

How can I implement them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provide an App Invite from SDK 4.0.

[image]

So using following code:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"appurl"];
//optionally set previewImageURL
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"imgeurl"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:self];
```

you can able to app invite. For full guide you can check [Facebook developer App Invites for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios)

Comment: but i already used  Version 2.0 with login and logout . i want to  change my completed project for this..

Comment: sir you have to change for facebook done lots of change might be your login method stop working very soon.